# How to remove space between string after paste it in vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two input which both need to remove the space between the string
I used **event.clipboardData.setData** but it didn't work
After that, I used **this.Name_of_my_state** But it returns both pasted item and removed space Item.
Let's take a look at my code to make it clear

```html
<template>
  <span>
    <input class="form-control inputHeight"
        @keydown.space.prevent
        @paste.space="remove_on_paste"
        v-model="floatingData.from_id">
    <input class="form-control inputHeight"
        @keydown.space.prevent
        @paste.space="remove_on_paste"
        v-model="floatingData.to_id">
  </span>
</template>
```

First I tried this but didn't work

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      floatingData: {
        from_id: "",
        to_id: ""
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    // Remove space on paste
    remove_on_paste(event) {
        let main_text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");
        event.clipboardData.setData("text", main_text.replace(/\D/g, ""));
    }
  }
})
```

Result:

[image: Result 1]

Then I tried this that pasted both copied and replaced value

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      floatingData: {
        from_id: "",
        to_id: ""
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    // Remove space on paste
    remove_on_paste(event) {
        let main_text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");
        this.floatingData.from_id = main_text.replace(/\D/g, "");
    }
  }
})
```

Result:

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Can't seem to be able to reproduce this issue. Can you provide an example input and the expected result?

Comment: When I want to copy a string like this "2847      " I expect the code to return this "2847".
I expect the code to remove the space between or before or after the text that will paste.

Comment: You can remove the whitespaces before and after the text with the function `trim()`

Comment: @ReinhardSchnetzinger Thanks for your response.  My issue is non of the function I tried doesn't work.
actually, they didn't return the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use watchers for this:

```js
data()
{
  return {
    first_input: '',
    second_input: '',
  }
},
watch:
{
  first_input()
  {
    this.$nextTick(() =>
    {
      this.first_input = this.first_input.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    })
  },
  second_input()
  {
    this.$nextTick(() =>
    {
      this.second_input = this.second_input.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    })
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the behavior I think you requested, where you can paste in a string with tailing whitespace, and it will be trimmed. The trick is to prevent the browser from doing anything after the paste using `event.preventDefault()` and using `main_text.trim()` to remove whitespace. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

(Tested on Google Chrome 91, using [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-grothendieck-e14wu?file=/src/App.vue))

```html
<template>
  <span>
    <input class="form-control inputHeight"
        @keydown.space.prevent
        @paste.space="remove_on_paste"
        v-model="floatingData.from_id">
    <input class="form-control inputHeight"
        @keydown.space.prevent
        @paste.space="remove_on_paste"
        v-model="floatingData.to_id">
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      floatingData: {
        from_id: "",
        to_id: ""
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    // Remove space on paste
    remove_on_paste(event) {
      let main_text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");

      event.preventDefault();
      this.floatingData.from_id = main_text.trim();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```